# How to allocate memory in loop?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management

I want to create 10 instance for Foo

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args) {

        foreach (var _ in Enumerable.Range(1, 10)) 
        {
            var foo = new Foo();
        }

        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```

But I use the diagnostic tool from VS2019 to trace the heap memory , it shows only 1 count.

Why is not 10 count for Foo type? There is should be 10 instance memory of Foo in heap ,but only one point to 'foo' stack. Please give me some advise, thanks.

[image]

--------update-------

@TaW : I refer to your advise , I create 10 instance outside of loop.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Foo foo;
        foo = new Foo();
        foo = new Foo();
        foo = new Foo();
        foo = new Foo();
        foo = new Foo();
        foo = new Foo();
        foo = new Foo();
        foo = new Foo();
        foo = new Foo();
        foo = new Foo();


        Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

But the diagnostic tool still display only one count in managed heap.

[image]

------Another Finding--------

I try to loop 100K times to create Foo instance and I add a byte[] of allocating 1024 size in Foo type

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        foreach (var _ in Enumerable.Range(0, 100000))  {

            var foo = new Foo();

        }

        Console.ReadKey();

    }

class Foo
{
    private byte[] bytes;
    public Foo()
    {
        bytes = new byte[1024];
    }

}
```

The diagnostic tool still display one count in managed heap and don't detect any GC on the process memory. It seems don't work.
[image]

I try to use .Net Object Allocation Tracking in `Debug` -> 
`Performance Profiler` -> `.Net Object Allocation Tracking` to monitor it.

The report is expected that there are 100K times allocation and trigger GC.

[image]

[image]

Now , I get more confused about the outstanding difference between `diagnostic tool`  and `.Net Object Allocation Tracking`.

Comment: Probably because the instance is garbage-collected away on every loop.

Comment: Add the items to a list, they won't get touched by the GC that way.

Comment: You need to declare them outside of the loop. Look up 'scope' !

Comment: There wont be a pointer to that instance on the heap which makes it suitable for GC, which in this case might be collected immediately

Comment: _There is should be 10 instance memory of Foo_ and how would you refer to them???

Comment: Actually all 10 are out of scope.

Comment: Yes, indeed. But, in terms of the question title no memory at all is allocated by the loop.

Comment: @Taw, please give some advice on my update. Thanks.

Comment: As Henk has suggested: Create a `List<Foo>` outside of the loop and add the new instances in the loop to it!  - The GC is not easily understood/predicted as it does its work in way that optimize various things, ie not just memory but also speed and number of interferences.

Comment: @TaW - Can I understand that as thoes variable don't use in anywhere, the optimizer detect this behavior in order to save memory for application , so only create an instance as no impact for applicaion.

Comment: All reference variables internally have a reference count. It goes to 1 when you declare it and increases whenever you create a ref. copy. It goes down by 1 when any of those references go 'out of scope' and the variable may get garbage collected when its use count is 0 and when the GC has time or when the memory gets scarce.

Comment: @TaW - .net does not use reference counting. We would go nuts breaking up cycles if it did.

Answer (score 1):

1. whenever GC feels like it, frankly; the variable is never read, so
   it is always eligible
2. `foo` is the variable - that has a fixed position on the stack for
   the reference; however, each `new Foo()` is a different object,
   created somewhere in the available heap space; different each time
3. no difference whatsoever; strictly speaking there are some
   complexities involving the actual declaration point of the variable
   (in IL) and how while is actually implemented - but that would only
   show after exiting the loop. And since on each iteration you
   immediately allocate it, there is no tangible difference here